# Select page/template from the permalink url

Tags: permalinks, pages, templates

I use permalinks like `example.com/projects/project1` for my project pages. They use all the same template. I want to access another template with more details on the project by adding `/details` to the URL. I don't want to nest/create more pages though. I want to keep my single project page in the admin area to maintain all the info.

Is this possible? Maybe with `.htaccess` or something in the `functions.php`?

Comment: search this site for [`add_rewrite_endpoint`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=add_rewrite_endpoint).

Comment: Hi Milo, thanks for the heads up. In the end I've chosen to use a mixture of add_filter "query_vars" and "page_template". THanks for the help!